# "Field has incomplete type" question for classes that reference themselves

Tags: c++, field

I'm new to C++ from Java, so apologies for the basic question. I'm trying to make just a simple Node class for a tree structure, and running into a "field has incomplete type TreeNode" error on the TreeNode children[] line. Is it illegal to have self-referential classes in c++? The code works in Java.

I tried researching the issue, but all questions I found were for more complicated issues, and I'm just trying to understand the basics right now.

```
/*
 * TreeNode.h
 *
 *  Created on: Aug 16, 2019
 *      Author: dbarrett24
 */

#ifndef TREENODE_H_
#define TREENODE_H_

class TreeNode {
public:
    int value;
    TreeNode children [];
    TreeNode(int x, TreeNode kids[]);
    virtual ~TreeNode();
};

#endif /* TREENODE_H_ */
```

Comment: I think your problem is `TreeNode children [];`. That's not valid in C++, I think. Try a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or something else instead.

Comment: The problem here is the "from Java" part. Despite the very similar syntax, C++ is not Java, and classes and objects in C++ are fundamentally different from classes and objects in Java. You will do yourself a big favor if you completely forget everything about Java, while learning C++, and start from the beginning, and a good C++ book. The rest of the comments and questions here will explain what this specific problem is all about, but, in general, you cannot equate Java and C++. If you continue drawing mental analogies between Java and C++ you will keep going sideways, like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your underlying problem is that you assume C++ works like Java.   And you are making that assumption in a context where C++ is emphatically different from Java.

The "incomplete type" error is because of

```
TreeNode children [];
```

since declaring an array member of a class without a dimension gives an incomplete type  (an array with unknown dimension is incomplete).

If you were to supply an array dimension that is known at compile time.

```
TreeNode children [25];
```

that would be a complete type, but is still invalid within class `TreeNode` since it effectively means that a `TreeNode` object contains `25` instances of `TreeNode`, each of which contains 25 instances of `TreeNode` - which is infinitely recursive containment.

Unlike Java, which uses reference semantics by default, C++ uses value semantics.   A consequence of this is that an object of type `TreeNode` cannot contain an instance of `TreeNode` (i.e. another complete object of type `TreeNode`) and cannot contain an array of `TreeNode` (i.e.  a complete SET of objects of type `TreeNode`).

The way to handle that is by indirection - explicitly using a code construct that allows use of pointer or reference semantics.    One example is

```
#include <vector>
class TreeNode
{
 public:
     int value;
     std:vector<TreeNode> children;
     TreeNode(int x, TreeNode kids[], std::size_t n);
     virtual ~TreeNode();
};
```

since a `std::vector<TreeNode>` actually (in effect) contains a pointer to a dynamically allocated array of `TreeNode`, and manages dynamic allocation and deallocation of `TreeNode` objects at run time.

The constructor declaration in the above

```
  TreeNode(int x, TreeNode kids[], std::size_t n);
```

works a little differently than you expect.   I am adding third argument, `n`, to represent the number of kids being passed since there is no way in standard C++ to obtain the number of elements of an array argument.   The second argument can use array syntax, but this is actually treated by the compiler as a pointer.   So the above constructor declaration is actually equivalent to

```
  TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *kids, std::size_t n);
```

Either way, this constructor needs to be defined.   One way would be

```
TreeNode::TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *kids, std::size_t n) : children(n)
{
      // presumably also do something with x

      for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
          children[i] = kids[i];
}
```

where the `children(n)` in the constructor initialiser list has the effect, for a `std::vector`, of setting the number of elements to `n`.

An even better way to implement the constructoror would be to use the fact that a `std::vector` can be initialised using a pair of iterators

```
TreeNode::TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *kids, std::size_t n) : children(kids, kids + n)
{
      // presumably also do something with x
}
```

where `children(kids, kids + n)` uses pointer syntax.  `kids` is equivalent to `&kids[0]` (i.e. the address of the first element of a passed array) and `kids + n` is equivalent to `&kids[n]` (i.e. the address of the "one past the end" element of `kids`).

Comment: Thanks, this is really well put. Clearly my notions of ease of transitioning from Java to C++ were oversimplified.

Comment: @flacko32 - It's a common misunderstanding - it also catches people out when migrating from C++ to Java. Java has been marketed in various ways - one of which is as a language without some of the problems of C++, which obscures the fact they are very different languages - each with advantages and disadvantages. If you want to learn C++ effectively, it is better not to try to learn by analogy from Java. This time you got lucky, since your code simply didn't compile - which made it obvious there was a problem. There are also cases where the code would compile, but work differently.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the following class's member: `TreeNode children [];`. Ignoring the array syntax error in c++, `TreeNode` is the current class definition, and currently it's an incomplete type. You can use pointers to solve it (if you don't want to use std collections), or vector (which is one of the std collections). Consider something like this:

```
std::vector<TreeNode> children;
```

Or for future problems, in case you don't want collections (usually whenever you want just a single value):

```
std::shared_ptr<TreeNode> property_name;
```

Comment: You can in fact do `std::vector <TreeNode> children;`, which might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your class declaration cannot have a object of self type.
Though it can also have pointer to self type.

Actually what happening is, you are making an array of `TreeNode` which is calling `TreeNode()` to create new instance and that new instance of TreeNode also have `TreeNode children [];` which again calls `TreeNode()` to create this array, and this goes on and on.

Try replacing your code to:

```
class TreeNode {
public:
    int value;
    TreeNode *children[];
    TreeNode(int x, TreeNode kids[]);
    virtual ~TreeNode();
};
```

an array of pointers